# Visual Studio 2008 designer throws Error

Tags: visual-studio, designer

We have a project that was migrated from VS 2005 to 2008.

One form is using usercontrol. When I open this form I get following message from the designer:

> The variable '_usercontrol' is either
>   undeclared or was never assigned.
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String exceptionText, String
>   helpLink) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression
>   expression) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression
>   expression) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeStatement statement)

If I ignore this error and continue, the usercontrol declaration is removed from the designer. Can someone please advise how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: so what is "usercontrol" exactly? What kind of control is it, what does it do? Does it have any resource dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help:

[The variable `'<variable name>'` is either undeclared or was never assigned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4008y84t.aspx)